# Feed aggregator with E-mail/RSS channels

Tags: email, rss, product-rec

Which feed aggregators, besides FriendFeed, allow RSS and e-mail as input and output channels?

That is, allow to suscribe external RSS feeds and to write a post by e-mail, and allow to be notified both by RSS feed and by e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Yahoo pipes I believe you can add those pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of RSS reader in alliance with [Emails to RSS Forwarding Service](http://emails2rss.appspot.com)
The service provides RSS feed based on your emails that you can listen with a RSS reader.
[Guide how to setup it with gmail](http://emails2rss.appspot.com/help/gmail-forward-setup/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Google Reader](http://google.com/reader) with [Gmail](http://gmail.com) should do the trick

Comment: Google Reader? How is it possible to send your own feed items to email address in Google Reader?

Comment: i meant you can subscribe to feed with the reader and send/receive mail via gmail web interface. may be i didn't understand your requirement clearly